# Show user name on Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using Devise for users, but in view page when I trying to show the user name and surname I see only 0.

**View:**

```
    <% if user_signed_in?%>
        <div id="admin_bar">
            <ul>
                <li>Lapini lūgti, <%= current_user.name %> <%= current_user.surname %> administratora panelī!</li>
            </ul>
        </div>  
    <% end %>
```

**User migration:**

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|

      t.integer :name,      :null => false
      t.integer :surname,   :null => false

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
  def self.down
    drop_table :users
  end
end
```

Devise migration which added Devise to my User:

```
class AddDeviseToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table(:users) do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              :null => false, :default => ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, :null => false, :default => ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, :default => 0
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      # t.string   :confirmation_token
      # t.datetime :confirmed_at
      # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, :default => 0 # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at

      ## Token authenticatable
      # t.string :authentication_token


      # Uncomment below if timestamps were not included in your original model.
      # t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                :unique => true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, :unique => true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   :unique => true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         :unique => true
    # add_index :users, :authentication_token, :unique => true
  end

  def self.down
    # By default, we don't want to make any assumption about how to roll back a migration when your
    # model already existed. Please edit below which fields you would like to remove in this migration.
  end
end
```

and my user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :name, :surname
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
end
```

What I am missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually people's name and surname are strings, not integers. Instead of this:

```
t.integer :name,      :null => false
t.integer :surname,   :null => false
```

use this:

```
t.string :name,      :null => false
t.string :surname,   :null => false
```

Comment: I feel so stupid about this mistake. Thank you. Seems like I am tired.